# Making Java String usable for a SQL Script

Tags: java, sql

If I have a string that looks like this:

```
This is a string
with single quotes ' all over
the ' place as well as
return characters
```

How would I convert this to a string that can be used in an INSERT statement?

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('<the above string>');
```

The string above has the problems that it has return characters as well as single quotes which would mess up the validity of the INSERT statement above.

**Edit:**  Sorry I probably should have been more clear.  I'm generating a SQL Script with INSERT statements, not executing SQL within a Java app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm generating a SQL Script with INSERT statements, not executing SQL within a Java app.

In that case, you'll have to generate an "escaped" version of the String. To do so, I'd suggest using the [ESAPI](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi) library from the OWASP project (if possible). See [Defense Option 3: Escaping All User Supplied Input](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_3:_Escaping_All_User_Supplied_Input) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Use PreparedStatement:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, theAboveString);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I'm not executing the SQL however.  I'm intending on generating a SQL Script that has INSERT statements in it for someone else to execute.

Answer (score 0):

To put a single quote inside of an SQL string, use it twice.

so

```
insert into mytable
values ('isn''t it lovely?')
```

So when generating the sql script, just replace all single quotes with double quotes before tacking the beginning and ending single quotes onto it.

Answer (score 0):

why dont use escape the single quotes like below

This is a string 
with single quotes \' all over 
the \' place as well as 
return characters